# Execute command on remote host fails

Tags: shell, shell-script, ssh, here-document

I'm trying to execute some commands on remote host like this :

```
ssh -t -t -l user 172.20.20.20 <<EOF
  pid=$(ps -ef | grep [a]pp-management | awk '{print $2}') && kill -9 $pid && rm -rf CI/*
EOF
```

What happens is that I remain logged at remote server and the kill is not executed :

```
user@ubuntu:~$ pid= && kill -9  && rm -rf CI/*
kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
```

Neither `rm` gets executed, what am I doing wrong?

I see that nothing get passed to kill -9 command, why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expansions introduced by `$` signs in the heredoc are evaluated locally, before generating the string that is passed as input to the `ssh` command.

To avoid this, escape the commands in your heredoc, for instance with quotes around `EOF`

```
ssh ... <<"EOF"
```

Comment: thanks for the response, how do I get back to my current shell, after the command is executed I'm still in the remote server

Comment: @GandalfStormCrow You can divert ssh command to `/dev/null` to force it to return to your current shell after issuing the remote command something like this: `{ sleep 1; YOUR_REMOTE_COMMAND; } >/dev/null &`

Comment: And if you remove the `-t -t ` ? Any reason why  you put them in the first place ? I don't think those commands need a tty.